# Remove Action Button From Action Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I have implemented ActionBar Navigation using Fragment. In my App i have one Activity and rest is in Fragments. In my MainActivity i am implementing menu like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Two Fragments uses Navigation Drawer and in their respected fragments i am inflating menu buttons to sort items.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_button_shops, menu);
    }
```

Now the Problem is if i open the Fragment 1 it works perfectly. When i open fragment 2, it shows 2 button to sort, one from Fragment 1 and the second one from Fragment 2.

I have tried to hide the button but it didn't worked.
Any Help will be Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I make some MenuItems (the buttons I want to hide/show) in the declaration section of my Activity. I assign them in the onCreateOptionsMenu. Then, in code, I use `myItem.setVisible(true|false);`. Very simple.

Comment: I have already tried this, it is not working. I am surprised why the menu added in fragment 1 shown in fragment 2. As Every Fragment has its own menu.

Comment: I know this is a little old but see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inflate a new menu you are adding new items to the old `Menu` object, which is probably not what you intended.

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.removeItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in onResume() of fragments.

```
MenuItem item = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.menu.activity_main);
item.setVisible(false);
this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: this.invalidateOptionsMenu(); it required Api 11, i need it for Api 10 As well.

Comment: try using supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() for api level<11